# PyCharm: How can I use breakpoints in multithreaded code?

Tags: python, multithreading, pycharm

I want to use PyCharm, but I really need to use breakpoints in threads other than the main thread.

In this example code, PyCharm does not break within the threaded function.  Is there a way to fix that?

```
import time, threading
def f():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        print 'tick-tock' # Put a breakpoint here...

th = threading.Thread(target=f)
th.start()
time.sleep(30)
print 'done.'
```

**Edit:** Platform details: Mac OS 10.9, Python 2.7.6, PyCharm 3.4.1

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me with PyCharm and python3.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the datapoint.  I wonder why it isn't working for me... Can I ask what platform you're using? (I'll add my platform to the question text.)

Comment: Pycharm 3.4.1 (professional) with Python 3 under Win 7 x64. But I also use it under Linux Mint and I'm almost certain it works there just as well.

Comment: I can also confirm that it works for me just fine. PyCharm 3.4.1 professional, Python 2 under Arch Linux.

Comment: 2017-02-07: Still not working for me (version 2016.3.2, OSX). Maybe it's an OSX issue.

Answer (score 5):

This thread is quite old, but it still worth mentioning [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009074380-PyCharm-not-debugging-into-new-Thread) solution:

open "Edit Configurations..." and add this line:

`PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO;PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO;`

into the the beginning of Environment variables section:

[image]

This seems to allow breakpoints to stop while running in a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import threading
import pdb

def f():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
        print 'tick-tock' # Put a breakpoint here...
        pdb.set_trace()

th = threading.Thread(target=f)
th.start()
time.sleep(30)
print 'done.'
```

During execution:

```
┌───┤/tmp├──────────────────────────────────────┤0.43├──────┤20140612.211049├───
└─┤goncalog@darkside:pts/1│ret=1├────> python test.py 
tick-tock
> /tmp/test.py(8)f()
-> while True:
(Pdb) list
  3     import time
  4     import threading
  5     import pdb
  6     
  7     def f():
  8  ->     while True:
  9             time.sleep(1.0)
 10             print 'tick-tock' # Put a breakpoint here...
 11             pdb.set_trace()
 12     
 13     th = threading.Thread(target=f)
(Pdb) c
tick-tock
> /tmp/test.py(8)f()
-> while True:
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.  However, a solution that enables multithread breakpoint functionality in PyCharm would be preferable.  My program is an interactive application, so I'd like to set breakpoints without editing the source code and re-launching the app.